# Parse - User beforeSave and afterSave triggers not called when verifying email

Tags: parse-platform

I need to run some Cloud Code when a user verified its email through built-in Parse Email Verification feature:

https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#users-email-verification

But `afterSave` and `beforeSave` triggers are ignored when user `emailVerified` is set to true when confirmation link is clicked.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this issue (e.g., if it's a bug), but a quick workaround could be to use a background job to query for users who have emailVerified == true and then store a boolean to track that you've ran your function for that user's post email-verification.

Comment: Yeah, thanks I saw this workaround. It's not ideal but it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse is no longer supported by Facebook and has been open-sourced at [parse-community/parse-server](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server)